# Load program binaries at boot

Tags: linux, shell-script, boot, cache, caching

I've written some utility scripts for my linux system. The problem is that the first invocation of programs lag a bit, I suppose it's the disk delay. Is there a way I can cache these scripts without running them at boot so that the usage is smoother?

Comment: Without insight into what's causing the delay, it's hard to work around. There is no way to commit anything to memory across reboots, but I'd challenge your assumption that disk load time is the cause. Is there a reason you need to reboot so often that one second causes a problem?

Comment: I think it's the disk delay because the lag is there only during the first invocation. I don't want to save anything across reboots, I just want to cache the program scripts to ram at boot. As the question says, I want the system to work smoothly, that's the only reason.

Comment: Running it is probably the best way to speed up the load time. E.g. copying it to a ramdisk before running it just pushes the disk read to a separate, additional process, so that's unlikely to accomplish what you want. Like you surmise, the first load probably caches it in memory, but there's not really any better way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for the script, you can load it into the cache with

```
cat /path/to/script >/dev/null
```

You can do this as well for any file that's involed, e.g. script interpreters and their shared libraries

```
exec  >/dev/null
cat /path/to/my/scripts/*
for interpreter in /bin/sh /usr/bin/perl; do
  cat "$interpreter"
  ldd "$interpreter" | sed -n 's!^[^/]*!!; /^\// s! .*!!p' | xargs cat
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that these utility scripts are running into resource contention at system startup, you can delay their execution by a couple of mintes.  In your cron table, have an entry such as:

```
@reboot sleep 120; cd /path/to/working/directory; ./script.sh 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The script run fine, I just want to avoid the one second lag at the first run. Can it be done without executing the programs.